# Program to print n non Fibonacci numbers

Tags: c

I wrote the following code, but it is not giving the correct output. For input n = 5, the output should be 4 6 7 9 10, but my output is 4 5 6 7 8. Can anyone help me out? Where am I going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int isFibo(int n){
    if(n<=0)
        return 1;
    if(n==1)
        return 1;
    if(n==2)
        return 1;
    int t1=0;
    int t2=1,t3;
    //int i=1;
    while(t3<n){
        t3=t1+t2;
        t1=t2;
        t2=t3;
        if(t3==n)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
void printNonFibo(int n){
    int i=0,count=0;
    while(count<n){
        if(!isFibo(i))
        {
            printf("\nNon Fibo: %d ",i);
            count++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printNonFibo(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and step thru the code line by line to investigate where things start going wrong. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: i did that all! still can't find the error...

Comment: Consider: `while(t3<n)` what is the value of `t3` when the loop starts?

Comment: the isFibo() function is working perfectly fine, I checked that for various inputs. But when it's used in the printNonFibo() function, it only works for the 1st term. Donno why.

Comment: It's obviously not working fine. For it to be working fine it would need to work every single time right? `t3` is uninitalised and using an unintialised variable is Undefined Behaviour. It may sometimes appear to "work" or any other unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: You're using `t3` before assigning it a value (or initializing it) in `while (t3 < n)` the very first time through the loop

Comment: Alright thanks guys,

Comment: `int t2=1,t3=0;`
This is all I had to do